# Error al parsear respuesta html

Tags: html, python, json, beautifulsoup

estoy haciendo una consulta a esta página web:

[https://es.soccerway.com/a/block_competitions_index_club_domestic?block_id=page_competitions_1_block_competitions_index_club_domestic_4&callback_params={%22level%22:%222%22}&action=expandItem&params={%22area_id%22:%2267%22,%22level%22:2,%22item_key%22:%22area_id%22}](https://es.soccerway.com/a/block_competitions_index_club_domestic?block_id=page_competitions_1_block_competitions_index_club_domestic_4&callback_params=%7B%22level%22:%222%22%7D&action=expandItem&params=%7B%22area_id%22:%2267%22,%22level%22:2,%22item_key%22:%22area_id%22%7D)

, y soy incapaz de parsear el resultado que obtengo. Estoy utilizando beautifulsoup mediante python, pero no me reconoce ninguna de las etiquetas.

He probado eliminado todo el texto por delante de  para ver si así me interpretaba las etiquetas, pero tampoc.

Me podríais ayudar por favor? Os indico el resultado que me llega:

```
{"commands":[{"name":"insert","parameters":{"content":"<ul class=\"competitions\" data-level=\"2\" ><li class=\" odd\" ><div class=\"row\"><a href=\"\/national\/el-salvador\/primera-division\/c378\/\" class=\"competition\" >Primera Divisi\u00f3n<\/a><span class=\"type\">Domestic league<\/span><span class=\"season\">2021\/2022<\/span><\/div><\/li><li class=\" even\" ><div class=\"row\"><a href=\"\/national\/el-salvador\/copa-el-salvador\/c1622\/\" class=\"competition\" >Copa El Salvador<\/a><span class=\"type\">Domestic cup<\/span><span class=\"season\"><\/span><\/div><\/li><li class=\" odd\" ><div class=\"row\"><a href=\"\/national\/el-salvador\/play-offs-12\/c2073\/\" class=\"competition\" >Play-offs 1\/2<\/a><span class=\"type\">Domestic cup<\/span><span class=\"season\"><\/span><\/div><\/li><li class=\" even\" ><div class=\"row\"><a href=\"\/national\/el-salvador\/reserve-league\/c2170\/\" class=\"competition\" >Reserve League<\/a><span class=\"type\">Domestic league<\/span><span class=\"season\">2021\/2022<\/span><\/div><\/li><\/ul>\n","container":"li[data-area_id=\"67\"]","position":"bottom"}},{"name":"updateCallbackParams","parameters":{"params":{"level":"2"}}}],"timestamp":"Fri, 13 May 2022 12:48:05 +0200"}
```

Comment: Con qué código lo intentas parsear? ¿Parseas todo o una parte del JSON?
Además... viene tal cual? es extraño el uso de las comillas dobles por todas partes (como parte de JSON y como parte de los atributos del HTML)

Comment: Parece que lo que recibes es un json. La solución sería parsear primero el json y a partir de ahí parsear el html que contiene.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, el html que quiero viene dentro de un json. Primero he tenido que parsear el json, para sacar el commands/parameters/content/ y ahí ya tengo el html puro que estaba buscando.

```
texto_json = json.loads(request.text)
commands = (texto_json["commands"])[0]
parameters = (commands["parameters"])
content = parameters["content"]
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.